# List points from other layer where intersects with line

Tags: qgis, point, line, overlapping-features, intersect

I want to make an easy script for QGIS calc. I have 2 layers (points, and line).

Painting the line crosing by points. At end I want to automaticly fill fild (text attribute) with list of points.

I was do it like this:

```
array_to_string(
aggregate(
    layer:='SLupy', 
    aggregate:='array_agg', 
    expression:="id", 
    concatenator:=',',
    filter:=intersects( $geometry, geometry(@parent) ) 
    ) 
)
```

But there is mess, how to sort by as was writed first and last.
OR how to do it different way.
I was try to read first point from line like;

```
geom_to_wkt(start_point($geometry))
```

I don't know how to set list of point (or  read 'id' of first point form list of all). How can I do this?